# Creating new function in angularjs controller won't work

Tags: angularjs

When creating new function in angularjs controller and assign it to button with ng-click and function is simple,

```
function toLogin() {
    console.log("Entered function");
    $state.go('login');
}
```

I tried with $scope and still does not work. 
this is my controller:

```
'use strict';
```

angular.module('crudApp').controller('UserController',
    ['UserService', '$scope','$state',   function( UserService, $scope, $state) {

```
    var self = this;
    self.user = {};
    self.users=[];
    self.user.enabled = false;
    self.user.confirmationToken = '';
    self.loggedUser = null;
    self.submit = submit;
    self.getAllUsers = getAllUsers;
    self.createUser = createUser;
    self.updateUser = updateUser;
    self.removeUser = removeUser;
    self.editUser = editUser;
    self.reset = reset;
    self.firstNamePattern=/^[A-Z][a-z]*\S$/;
    self.lastNamePattern=/^[A-Z][a-z]*\S$/;
    self.userNamePattern= /^\S*$/;
    self.passwordPattern = /^\S*$/;
    self.phonePattern = /^[0-9]+\S$/;
    self.successMessage = '';
    self.errorMessage = '';
    self.done = false;

    self.onlyIntegers = /^\d+$/;
    self.onlyNumbers = /^\d+([,.]\d+)?$/;
    function toLogin() {
        console.log('Entered function');
       // $state.go('login');
    }
    function submit() {
        console.log('Submitting');
        if (self.user.id === undefined || self.user.id === null) {
            console.log('Saving New User', self.user);
            createUser(self.user);
        } else {
            updateUser(self.user, self.user.id);
            console.log('User updated with id ', self.user.id);
        }
    }
    $scope.moje = function () {
        console.log('Submitting');
        if (self.user.id === undefined || self.user.id === null) {
            console.log('Saving New User', self.user);
            createUser(self.user);
        } else {
            updateUser(self.user, self.user.id);
            console.log('User updated with id ', self.user.id);
        }
    }

    function createUser(user) {
        console.log('About to create user');
        UserService.createUser(user)
            .then(
                function (response) {
                    console.log('User created successfully');
                    self.successMessage = 'User created successfully';
                    self.errorMessage='';
                    self.done = true;
                    self.user={};
                    $scope.registerForm.$setPristine();
                    $scope.registerForm.$setUntouched();
                   // $state.reload();

                },
                function (errResponse) {
                    console.error('Error while creating User');
                    self.errorMessage = 'Error while creating User: ' + errResponse.data.errorMessage;
                    self.successMessage='';
                }
            );
    }


    function updateUser(user, id){
        console.log('About to update user');
        UserService.updateUser(user, id)
            .then(
                function (response){
                    console.log('User updated successfully');
                    self.successMessage='User updated successfully';
                    self.errorMessage='';
                    self.done = true;
                    $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while updating User');
                    self.errorMessage='Error while updating User '+errResponse.data;
                    self.successMessage='';
                }
            );
    }


    function removeUser(id){
        console.log('About to remove User with id '+id);
        UserService.removeUser(id)
            .then(
                function(){
                    console.log('User '+id + ' removed successfully');
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while removing user '+id +', Error :'+errResponse.data);
                }
            );
    }


    function getAllUsers(){
        return UserService.getAllUsers();
    }

    function editUser(id) {
        self.successMessage='';
        self.errorMessage='';
        UserService.getUser(id).then(
            function (user) {
                self.user = user;
            },
            function (errResponse) {
                console.error('Error while removing user ' + id + ', Error :' + errResponse.data);
            }
        );
    }
    function reset(){
        self.successMessage='';
        self.errorMessage='';
        self.user={};
        $scope.myForm.$setPristine(); //reset Form
    }
}


]);
```

And and I using ui-routing and this is where I assign controller to my view:

```
}).state('success',{
                url: '/success',
                templateUrl: 'partials/successMessage',
                controller: 'UserController',
                controllerAs: 'sCtrl'
            });
```

And the ftl part of code is here:

```
<button type="button" ng-click='sCtrl.toLogin()' class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

It won't even print to console, but when assigning older function it works perfectly, although it is much more complicated. Ps. Sorry for bad clarification at first, I am new to community and still learning a proper way to ask question.

Comment: We need to see this in context in order to help you. Post the relevant part of the controller which contain this function and how yo use this controller and particularly the function (in the view)

Comment: @lealceldeiro While in most cases you are right, this question's issue is obvious from the code he provided and can easily be answered, which Sajeetharan did.

Comment: @BShaps, see the OP's comment in the Sajeetharan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678309/creating-new-function-in-angularjs-controller-wont-work/49678326#49678326). That's why I've opted for not assuming what the OP didn't post in the first place.

Comment: This question is of the most basic concept in the AngularJS framework. Please search before asking a question like this!

Comment: I am new to the community, so sorry for bad clarification, I was doing it on Sajeetharan way at first. It looks to me like functions that are older are working but every new I write, even trivial ones don't.

Comment: try this instead: self.toLogin = function() {
        console.log('Entered function');
       // $state.go('login');
    }

Answer (score 1):

You're not registering the method to the controller, to do that.
Add this below in self.onlyNumbers

```
self.toLogin = toLogin;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use $scope

```
$scope.toLogin = function(){
 console.log("Entered function");
 $state.go('login');
}
```

Comment: But other functions are without $scope and they are working correctly. At first I was trying with $scope and it was not working. My browser load my js file correctly. I put this function into my controller that works 100% and it was not working. Even when I copy function that works and just change its name it won't work.

Comment: reproduce the issue with plunker

Comment: Something this simple should not be answered.